# How to use .OrderBy for multiple conditions, one only sometimes used?

Tags: c#, linq

Sorry if the title, is confusing, I had some trouble putting my problem into words.

I have a List, where every string is composed of 2 words, delimited by space.

For example:

```cs
{ "word1 word2", "wordA wordB", "dog cat", "mouse cat" }
```

I want to use OrderBy to sort the list by the 2nd word, if any words are equal, I then want to sort those by the 1st word. I'm having trouble figuring out how to handle the 2nd condition for this (sorting by 1st word only if 2nd words are equal).

I originally tried:

```
public List<string> SpecialSort(List<string> text)
{
    return text.OrderBy(x => x.Split(' ')[1]).ThenBy(x => x.Split(' ')[0]);
}
```

but this seems to just sort first by the 2nd word, and then re-sort everything by the 1st word. Is there a way for me to do this where I only sort by 1st word if the 2nd words are equal?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, so it can't possibly "seems to just sort first by the 2nd word, and then re-sort everything by the 1st word". I suspect that this is not your real code. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: [This is what I get if I fix your code](https://rextester.com/SWM59726) and that doesn't exhibit the behaviour you're referring to.

Comment: I think you can simplify the logic by just keeping the first .OrderBy() and removing the .ThenBy(). In the logic of if both words are equal, this means that the second word is also the first word. You can just order by x => x.Split(' ')[1] and that's it.

Comment: @KingOfArrows Given the attempted code, and the rest of the problem, I believe OP means when "cat" from "dog cat" matches "cat" from "mouse cat", those entries should then be sorted by the first word (i.e. "dog cat" before "mouse cat"). OP doesn't mean things like "cat cat".

Comment: `but this seems to just sort first by the 2nd word, and then re-sort everything by the 1st word.` Please share a [mcve] since that seems odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to split the text into words, while keeping the original text in a Select. Then sort the sequence and finally remove the split words.

> **Requirement**
> **Input**: a sequence of strings, every string has exactly one space.
> This space is neither the first nor the last character.
> The characters before this one and only space are defined as the first word.
> The characters after the space are defined as the second word.
> **Output**: Sort the sequence by 2nd word, then by 1st word.

```
IEnumerable<string> inputTexts = ...
const string splitChar = ' ';

// first add the split words
var sortedSequence = inputTexts.Select(txt => new
{
    Original = txt,
    Split = txt.Split(splitChar, StringSplitOptions.None),
})

// then sort by the split words
.OrderBy(splitTxt => splitTxt.Split[1])
.ThenBy(splitTxt => splitTxt.Split[0])

// finally remove the split words
.Select(splitTxt => splitTxt.Original);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create intermediate results within an `.OrderBy()` statement can be painful, cause the comparer needs to possibly call them multiple times on each object. Also to make it better maintainable I would write a class that gets the original value, creates the desired elements and feeding these intermediate objects into a specific comparer that can sort them. At the end just get the original value out of the intermediate class and you're done.

A rough sketch for your example would look something [like this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PGs3aa):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var words = new List<string>{"word1 word2", "wordA wordB", "dog cat", "mouse cat"};
        var ordered = words
            .Select(SpecialComparerInstance.Create)
            .OrderBy(special => special, SpecialComparer.Default)
            .Select(special => special.Value);

        foreach (var item in ordered)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}

public class SpecialComparerInstance
{
    public static SpecialComparerInstance Create(string value) => new SpecialComparerInstance(value);
    
    public SpecialComparerInstance(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
        
        var elements = value.Split(' ');
        
        if (elements.Length != 2)
            throw new ArgumentException("Must contain exactly one space character", nameof(value));
        
        Value = value;
        FirstOrderValue = elements[1];
        SecondOrderValue = elements[0];
    }

    public string Value { get; }

    public string FirstOrderValue { get; }

    public string SecondOrderValue { get; }
}

public class SpecialComparer : IComparer<SpecialComparerInstance>
{
    public static readonly IComparer<SpecialComparerInstance> Default = new SpecialComparer(StringComparer.Ordinal);
    
    private readonly StringComparer _comparer;

    public SpecialComparer(StringComparer comparer)
    {
        _comparer = comparer;
    }

    public int Compare(SpecialComparerInstance x, SpecialComparerInstance y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return 0;
            
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null))
            return 1;

        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return -1;

        var result = _comparer.Compare(x.FirstOrderValue, y.FirstOrderValue);

        if (result == 0)
            result = _comparer.Compare(x.SecondOrderValue, y.SecondOrderValue);

        return result;
    }
}
```